# Not using O_SYNC flag is deleting the file if there is a system crash

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I have an application writing the data generated from a source to a file onto sdcard.

If the file was created using O_SYNC flag, I am seeing performance hit. I removed the flag to avoid this performance hit.

But while data is being written to this file and if system crashes, this file is not there anymore on sdcard. But if the file is created with O_SYNC, file is present.

Is there a way to retain the file(prevent from deleting) when system crashed without impact performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, there isn't if you insist on having no impact on performance.

To improve file system performance, data and metadata is kept in buffer cache in RAM. Both data and metadata is synced with disk on a periodic basis. When the system crashes data which is in RAM at that time is obviously lost.

There are two aspects to this. The actual file data which is the contents of the file, and the file's metadata which represent the file within the file system and contribute to file system's internal consistency. What you can do is sync data and/or metadata  yourself with your own periodicity. Say, every large block of data that you write. That way you may lose only the latest part of the file's data, but most of the file would be there.

Please take a look at `fsync(2)`, `fdatasync(2)`, `sync(2)`, `fsync(2)`, and see if you can use one or more of these (or similar) functions depending on your needs.